# Duplex printing in google chrome from javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing, duplex

How to tick the "duplex printing" in Google Chrome from JavaScript when executing `window.print()`?

Or is there a key when you run Google Chrome, which by default sets this option?

Answer (score 0):

You don't get much say about the print options. Basically all you can do is style the page in different ways when entering (`onbeforeprint`) and exiting (`onafterprint`) printing session, but that's it.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing for more info.